# Can this property of sets be detected by the subset relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Consider a set $S$ of sets, and an element $s$ of $S$. It is very easy to say that $s$ is a maximal element of $S$ under the subset order. However, I am interested in a strictly stronger property. I want to be able to say that $s$ has at least one element that is in no other set of $S$. This is indeed strictly stronger than just saying $s$ is a maximal element. My question is, is this even possible? That is, in the structure $(S;s,\subseteq)$, is it possible to characterize that $s$ has that property using a first-order formula?

Comment: How does one say that $s$ is a maximal element of $S$?

Comment: @Karl $\forall x (s\subseteq x\rightarrow s=x)$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that S is the domain of discourse and not another constant symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is impossible. For example, consider $S=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1,2\}\}$ and $S'=\{\{0\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}$ with $s=\{0,1,2\}$ in both cases.

In $S$, $s$ satisfies your property. In $S'$, $s$ does not satisfy your property. But as structures in the language $L=\{\subseteq,s\}$, $S$ and $S'$ are isomorphic, so they satisfy all the same $L$-sentences. Thus,  your  property is not expressible by an $L$-sentence.

Comment: What is the proof that those structures are isomorphic? That is not obvious to me.

Comment: @user107952 Come on, each structure only has $3$ elements, how hard can it be? Hint: The isomorphism $S\to S'$ maps $\{0\}\mapsto \{0\}$, $\{1\}\mapsto \{1,2\}$, and $\{0,1,2\}\mapsto \{0,1,2\}$...

Comment: Both sets have $3$ elements and the isomorphism preserves inclusion...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you could express that there is an element $x$ in $s$ such that if $x$ is in another set $t$ in $S$, then $s=t$

$\exists x\in s[\forall t\in S[ x\in t\Rightarrow s=t]]$

Comment: The OP wants an answer using the $\subseteq$ relation but not the $\in$ relation.